# Cancelling asynctask for list view adapter before its finished

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, adapter

I need to cancel my asynctask populating a list view adapter before it has finished by pressing back button. By this code

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.seatadapter, null);

         TextView text3=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
         ProgressBar progressBar1=(ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
         TextView predic=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
         TextView classs=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
         ImageView img1=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

new update(classs,predic, text3, progressBar1,img1).execute(tarinname.get(position), Date.get(position), Ffrom.get(position), Tto.get(position), Ccl.get(position));

class update extends AsyncTask{

@Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

Code For Json Parsing....
}
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (this.result.contains("CurrentStatus")) {
                 progressBar.setVisibility(progressBar.GONE);

                 t.setVisibility(t.VISIBLE);
                 t3.setVisibility(t3.VISIBLE);
                im1.setVisibility(im1.VISIBLE);

                 t3.setText("Class "+TravelClass);

                 t1.setText(perdcition);

                 if (ConfirmTktStatus.contains("Confirm")) {
                    im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_green);

                }
                 if (ConfirmTktStatus.contains("Probable")) {

                    }
                 if (ConfirmTktStatus.contains("No Chance")) {

                    }

                t.setText(var1);

            }else {
                 progressBar.setVisibility(progressBar.GONE);
            }


                Toast.makeText(context, var, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

This is the adapter Class and we unable to cancel it by pressing back button during its process. On pressing back button the activity is closed but the background task continues.

```
@Override
            protected void onCancelled() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCancelled();
                ((Activity)context).finish();

            }
```

I tried this already but of no use..!!

Comment: How about [cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)) metod?

Comment: update the question what i had tried..!!

Comment: Look what you do: You finish activity when task is cancelled. You should cancel task when activity is finishing.  You should hold your AsynkTask instance in some variable and cancel it in activity onStop lifecycle callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create a list to store current AsyncTask, then cancel it anytime you want

```
for (AsyncTask myAsyncTask : myAsyncTasks) {
    if (myAsyncTask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)) {
        myAsyncTask.cancel(true);
    }
}
myAsyncTasks.clear();
```

Detail for your code:

```
private List<AsyncTask> myAsyncTasks = new ArrayList<>();
public void addRunningTask(AsyncTask task) {
    myAsyncTasks.add(task);
}

public void cancelRunningTasks() {
    for (AsyncTask myAsyncTask : myAsyncTasks) {
        if (myAsyncTask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)) {
            myAsyncTask.cancel(true);
        }
    }
    myAsyncTasks.clear();
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    cancelRunningTasks();
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.seatadapter, null);

         TextView text3=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
         ProgressBar progressBar1=(ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
         TextView predic=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
         TextView classs=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
         ImageView img1=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

AsyncTask task = new update(classs,predic, text3, progressBar1,img1);
task.execute(tarinname.get(position), Date.get(position), Ffrom.get(position), Tto.get(position), Ccl.get(position));
addRunningTask(task);

class update extends AsyncTask{

@Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

Code For Json Parsing....
}
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (this.result.contains("CurrentStatus")) {
                 progressBar.setVisibility(progressBar.GONE);

                 t.setVisibility(t.VISIBLE);
                 t3.setVisibility(t3.VISIBLE);
                im1.setVisibility(im1.VISIBLE);

                 t3.setText("Class "+TravelClass);

                 t1.setText(perdcition);

                 if (ConfirmTktStatus.contains("Confirm")) {
                    im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_green);

                }
                 if (ConfirmTktStatus.contains("Probable")) {

                    }
                 if (ConfirmTktStatus.contains("No Chance")) {

                    }

                t.setText(var1);

            }else {
                 progressBar.setVisibility(progressBar.GONE);
            }


                Toast.makeText(context, var, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Comment: where do i put this code..?? in doInBackGround or somewhere else..?? I was pasting it in adapter..!!

Comment: First, you should insert task to list by:   AsyncTask task = new update(classs,predic, text3, progressBar1,img1)); task.execute...;myAsyncTasks.add(task); then you cancel them when pressing back button

Comment: Init Array list  and "update" is the asynctask class name

ArrayList<update> upd;
Defined the array list
upd=new ArrayList<SeatAdapter.update>();
new update(classs,predic,text3,progressBar1, img1).execute(tarinname.get(position),Date.get(position), Ffrom.get(position),Tto.get(position),Ccl.get(position));

@Override 
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
     for (AsyncTask myAsyncTask : upd) {
         if (myAsyncTask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)) {
             myAsyncTask.cancel(true);
         }
     }
     upd.clear();

Comment: You create an Util class for 2 methods: insert to myAsyncTasks , and cancel task in myAsyncTasks. Like this: private static List<AsyncTask> myAsyncTasks = new ArrayList<>();
public static void addRunningTask(AsyncTask task) {
 myAsyncTasks.add(task);
}

public static void cancelRunningTasks() {
 for (AsyncTask myAsyncTask : myAsyncTasks) {
  if (myAsyncTask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)) {
   myAsyncTask.cancel(true);
  }
 }
 myAsyncTasks.clear();
}

Comment: Thanks for the code but there were some errors like the IDE forced me to remover override backpressed method as it cannot be used in adapter..!

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly fine..!!! I just called the onBackPressed in the onPostExecute()

Comment: You should add the cancel method in the onBackPressed of your current activity. Not add inside adapter

Comment: The whole code is inside the adapter and i had already called the cancelRunningTask method inside the onBackPressed..!! But then also no luck..!!

Comment: inside Adapter you only add ...addRunningTask... then you should go to the activity that create the adapter and override onBackPressed() with cancelAsyncTask...